# I have a database and along with multiple record of same date and related amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database and with multiple records of the same date and related amount but I only want a single record and that is **date related total amount**

```
No.       Date                   name   amt
----    -----------------------  -----  ----
4   2012-07-27 10:47:50.000  zerox  15  
5   2012-07-27 12:22:16.000  bag    30  
6   2012-07-28 10:47:50.000  zerox  25  
7   2012-07-28 12:22:16.000  bag    30
```

I want this:

```
-----------------
date         totamt
----------   -------
2012-07-27   45
2012-07-28   55
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. The code formatting is important for visualization. Take your time to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing

Comment: Which **version** of SQL Server are you using? 2000? 2005? 2008? 2008 R2? 2012 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your 'date' column doesn't get in the way, the following should work.

```
SELECT
     CAST(date AS DATE),
     SUM(amt) AS totamt
FROM TableName
GROUP BY CAST(date AS DATE)
```

Comment: You have to cast to date first, or else grouping will not work as expected

Comment: I corrected it as soon as I saved :)  I almost corrected the escaping the 'date' field as well but didn't want to edit it again. :)

Comment: This will work **IF** the OP is using SQL Server **2008** or newer (since the `DATE` type is a new feature in the 2008 version)

Comment: when i using simple query this is working fine but when binding the data through gridview this is not working and throws the error...  DataBinding: 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' does not contain a property with the name 'ExpenseDate'.

Comment: I'd have to see your GridView definition but I am assuming whatever class you are binding from doesn't have a public 'ExpenseDate' property or your DataTable doesn't have a column named 'ExpenseDate'.  Verify your 'DataField' matches something on the GridView's data source or context.

Answer (score 1):

```
select cast([date] as Date) as [Date], 
       sum(amt) TotAmt
from YourTable
group by cast([date] as Date)
```

Comment: This will work **IF** the OP is using SQL Server **2008** or newer (since the `DATE` type is a new feature in the 2008 version)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table orders(Num int,Date datetime,name varchar(100),amt float)
INSERT INTO orders
VALUES(4,'2012-07-27 10:47:50.000','zerox',15),
(5,'2012-07-27 12:22:16.000','bag',    30),  
(6,'2012-07-28 10:47:50.000','zerox',  25),    
(7,'2012-07-28 12:22:16.000','bag',    30)  

select cast(date as date) date,SUM(amt) sumAmt from orders
group by cast(date as date)
```

Comment: This will work **IF** the OP is using SQL Server **2008** or newer (since the `DATE` type is a new feature in the 2008 version)

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this new solution:

```
select convert(varchar,date,101) date,SUM(amt) sumAmt from orders
group by convert(varchar,date,101)
```